# Flutter: How to export a screen as a PDF

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf

I am trying to export the following screen:

[image]

as a PDF or Doc in Flutter.

So, the user will be able to enter some data in `TextField`s and when they finish they can download the whole page as a doc or PDF Document.

I am new so any suggestion will be greate.

Thank you Guys

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Flutter

There are a large set of packages that can deal with `PDF` in Flutter, wheter to create them such as in your case, or to preview them.

You can check this [gallery](https://fluttergems.dev/pdf/) of package from [fluttergemes.dev](https://fluttergems.dev/) to access a large set of `PDF` pacakges with Flutter.

Also you can find a large number of [videos in YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=create%20pdf%20with%20flutter) that explains how to create a `PDF` with Flutter.

Comment: Hello Moaz, thank you for you reply, but I need to create that screen in pdf with users data, so it will depend it what the user will write on the text fields. I have check your link an alot of videos, but there only creating a pdf without data entry, thank you

Comment: You're always welcome, actually you can put whatever you want in the `PDF`, just play around with it, you can do something like storing the values of the fields and display them as a normal text. Also check this link it might help you: https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/pdf/working-with-forms

Answer (score 1):

For someone who wants the same to take screenshots and then export in this example taking screenshots from widgets but in the package docs you can read how to take screenshots from the entire screen which is way easy.

Packages used:
https://pub.dev/packages/pdf
https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:date_format/date_format.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:screenshot/screenshot.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = '/home';

  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final ScreenshotController _screenshotController = ScreenshotController();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return return SafeArea(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        controller: _scrollController,
        child: RepaintBoundary(
          key: _globalKey,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 15.0,
              vertical: 0.0,
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _takeScreenshot(context, state);
                    },
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: const [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.picture_as_pdf,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // the widget that need to be the one we want to take screenshot
  _someWidget() {
    return Text('Hope it will help you');
  }

  String _getRandomString(int length) {
    const chars =
        'AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz1234567890';
    Random rnd = Random();
    return String.fromCharCodes(Iterable.generate(
        length, (_) => chars.codeUnitAt(rnd.nextInt(chars.length))));
  }
  
  // Take a screenshot
  _takeScreenshot(BuildContext context, OrderState state) {
    Widget container = _someWidget();
    _screenshotController
        .captureFromWidget(
            InheritedTheme.captureAll(context, Material(child: container)),
            delay: const Duration(seconds: 1))
        .then((capturedImage) {
      _exportScreenshotToPdf(context, capturedImage);
    });
  }

  // Export the screenshot as pdf
  Future<dynamic> _exportScreenshotToPdf(
      BuildContext context, Uint8List screenShot) async {
    pw.Document pdf = pw.Document();
    pdf.addPage(
      pw.Page(
        pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
        build: (context) {
          return pw.Expanded(
            child: pw.Image(pw.MemoryImage(screenShot), fit: pw.BoxFit.contain),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
    Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String documentPath = documentDirectory.path;

    File pdfFile = File(
        '$documentPath/${'${_getRandomString(10)}-${formatDate(DateTime.now(), [
          dd,
          '-',
          mm,
          '-',
          yyyy
        ])}'}.pdf');
    pdfFile.writeAsBytesSync(await pdf.save());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [this](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf), it is a library for creating a PDF with Widgets.